# How to write a cmp_list/3 function in Prolog?

Tags: list, comparison, prolog

> Write a predicate `cmp_list/3`, the first 2 arguments are 2 lists, and the last one is `Comparison` which means `ge`, `lt`, `le`, or `gt`.
>   `ge`: greater or equal
>   `lt`: less than
>   `le`: less or equal
>   `gt`: greater than
>   the output should be like this:
>   the first two lists represent a version of a software, and the function is used to compare two versions of a software to see which one is newer:

```
?- cmp_list([2,3,4], [2,3,5], C).
C = lt ;
C = le .

?- cmp_list([1,2,3,4], [1,1,8], C).
C = gt ;
C = ge .
```

Comment: Hint: There are two cases 3 cases to consider here - 1) both lists are empty, 2) one of the lists is empty, the other isnt, 3) both lists have 1 or more elements. You get the solution by reducing 3 to either 1 or 2.

Its not that I mind helping with homework, but please show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like homework, so I'll just give you a couple of hints.

- If both lists are empty, they're equal (`le` or `ge`).
- If first list is empty, you have something like `[], [V|Vt], ...` which could be the end of the recursion when comparing, say 1.2 and 1.2.3, so the third argument should be `lt`.
- Similarly, if the second list is empty, the third argument should be `gt`.
- If both are non-empty, you should compare the heads. If they differ, answer `gt` or `lt` accordingly. If they are equal, recurse on the tails.

Comment: 1.2.3 will be ge or gt 1.2, either one is correct. if both lists are empty, it should be le or ge