# How to write a function cmp-lst/3 in Prolog?

Tags: list, comparison, prolog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a cmp_list/3 function in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620781/how-to-write-a-cmp-list-3-function-in-prolog)

There are two function code provided:
The first one is below:

```
atom_integer(Atom, Int) :- atom_chars(Atom, C), number_chars(Int, C).
```

The second one is below:

```
integer_list([], []).
integer_list([Lst1|RLst1], [Lst2|RLst2]) :-
            atom_integer(Lst1, Lst2),
            integer_list(RLst1, RLst2).
```

Now, I need to write the cmp-list/3 function to get the following stuff:

```
?- cmp_list([2,3,4], [2,3,5], C).
C = lt ;
C = le .

?- cmp_list([1,2,3,4], [1,1,8], C).
C = gt ;
C = ge .
```

lt means less than; le means less or equal; gt means greater than; and ge means greater or equal.

The first list input and the second list input represent a version number of a software, and C means the comparison of the two versions.
This function should work for checking which version is newer.
For two empty input lists [], the answer can be le and ge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree with the other commenter on your duplicate question. This seems like homework. Why don't you show us some of your own code that attempts to do this?

Comment: I just began to learn Prolog, and I don't know how to let my functions return the "lt", "le", "gt", and "ge", actually I did write some code for this, but I couldn't continue after I made the base case.

Comment: You return values from a function by **binding** a value to a parameter that serves as the "return value". E.g. if you write a predicate ("function") that adds two integers, you could write ''add(A,B,C):- C is A+B.'', and expect that the first two parameters (A and B) are always "filled" with integer values, while the third is unbound, i.e. has not been bound to any value before your function is called.